# localhost redirected you too many times

Tags: php

I have a database and inside the database i have a user with a user type as admin.

As soon as i created a new user with user type member i was unable to login on my login page.

It gave me an error saying that :

```
localhost redirected you too many times.
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
 //checks if login session variable exist? If it does, display Logout
 session_start();
 if (isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] != "") {
    //link to page logout.php and displays the word Logout + username
    echo "<li><a href='logout.php'>Logout " . $_SESSION['login'] . "</a></li>";
    if (isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['usertype'] != "admin") {
        echo ("<li><a href='profile.php'>Profile</a></li>");
    } else {
        echo ("<li><a href='AdminPage.php'>Administrator</a></li>");
    }
    if ($_SESSION['login'] == "") {
        header("Location:login.php");
    }
    if ($_SESSION['login'] != "" && $_SESSION['usertype'] == "member") {
        header("location:home.php");
    }
} else {
    //else link to pagelogin.php and display the word Login
    echo ("<li><a href ='pagelogin.php'>Login</a></li>");
 }
?>
```

Also have a picture of the **login.php** codes :

[image]

Comment: Somewhere in the code is redirecting you... we can't help you without any code.

Comment: @ChinLeung i will put in different codes until the error is found

Comment: What file is this? Is it the login.php, or a header file?

Comment: @aynber this is the nav bar if user type is admin , it will display admin page or else display profile page for members

Comment: If the nav bar is included in login.php, it will keep redirecting. Either remove the nav bar from login.php, or have a check on `if($_SESSION['login'] == "")` to make sure that the location already isn't login.php.

Comment: @aynber i have added a picture of the login.php codes would you mind taking a look at it? Thanks

Comment: Images of code aren't helpful, especially without proper indentation. I'd recommend logging along the way to find out how far it's getting and where the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you want to check a variable if its empty you can use the empty(variable).

Then to write your code better:

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['usertype'] =="member")
{
header("location:home.php");
}
else if(empty($_SESSION['login']))
{
    header("location:login.php");
}
```